# Minus operator returns error ora-01722

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01722

I have **row**, which is a character field, but is compared to numeric values in conditions. This causes ORA-01722 invalid number error under some circumstances.

Instead of: **row** in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7)

It should be:   **row** in (‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’, ‘4’, ‘5’, ‘7’)

This query returns ORA-01722:

```
(select * from table@production)
minus
(select * from table)
```

How can the query above be modified?

Comment: Use `cast()`, `to_number()`, or `to_char()` to make them the same type.

Comment: `(select to_number(row, '9') from table@production) minus (select to_number(row, '9') from table)` still returns the same error. Thoughts?

Comment: Please show the table schemas for the two tables.  Your query shows no conditions.

Comment: It means you have non-numeric values for `row` in at least one row in at least one of the tables. If you can't locate and fix those, you'll have to convert the numeric conditions to strings. Your sample query isn't doing the `in` comparison so the question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Can you create an example on SQL Fiddle showing your problem?

Comment: This is the solution to the similar problem:
[Ora-01722: invalid number using count(1) on minus operator of two views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67419441/ora-01722-invalid-number-using-count1-on-minus-operator-of-two-views)