# ora-01722 invalid number using count(1) on minus operator of two views

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01722

I've got an error ora-01722: invalid number. Tried to_char, cast functions, nothing helps. I've got the following SQL, where PERSON_DOCS and PERSON_DOCS_NEW are the views and the field DOCTYPENAME is calculated using subselect inside the views and is of type varchar2(70), and is null for all rows in both views.

```
    select count(1) from 
     (select DOCTYPENAME
        from PERSON_DOCS 
      minus 
      select DOCTYPENAME
        from PERSON_DOCS_NEW)
```

Views at the moment are identical:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PERSON_DOCS AS
  select

...,

(select lr.ll_remark
   from table1 ln,
        table2 lv,
        table3 lr
  where ln.short_name = 'DOC.TYPE'
    and ln.table_no = lv.table_no
    and lv.table_no = lr.table_no
    and lv.vetting_table = c.doc_type) as DOCTYPENAME,
 
...

from table0 c
```

Tried to_char, cast functions on the subselect inside the view, doesn't help.

Table3 DDL statement, from which the value comes:

```
CREATE TABLE table3
   (TABLE_NO VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
    LL_REMARK VARCHAR2(70 BYTE)
   ) ;

CREATE TABLE table1
   (TABLE_NO VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
    SHORT_NAME VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
   );

CREATE TABLE table2
   (TABLE_NO VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
    VETTING_TABLE VARCHAR2(35 BYTE), 
    APPLICATION VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
   );

CREATE TABLE table0
   (CUSTOMER_CODE VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    DOC_TYPE NUMBER
   );
```

Comment: please edit the question and show the complete table definitions that are referenced in the views, and example data. thanks

Comment: When I just execute [select DOCTYPENAME  from PERSON_DOCS  minus  select DOCTYPENAME from PERSON_DOCS_NEW] then there is no error, empty set is returned. An error occurs only when select count(1) on this select statement is used.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. That would be helpful.

Comment: Your basic select statement is valid, so the issue must be within the views. Perhaps there is an implicit conversion such that a numeric gets compared to a non-numeric. Or, the optimizer may be re-writing the queries and causing the problem.

Comment: laf8 thank you, yes, there was an implicit conversion, see the answer below.

Comment: What is `count(1)`? In SQL the standard expression is `count(*)`.

Comment: The result of count(1) is always the same as result of count( * ). For me it's just a habit, because years ago I thought that count(1) works faster. But it seems that it works the same as count(*) from performance point of view. See an article: https://learnsql.com/blog/difference-between-count-distinct/#:~:text=The%20simple%20answer%20is%20no,COUNT(1)%20are%20identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your query there is an implicit type conversion. Just use `explain plan` of your query and in the predicates section or in the `projection` you will see something like `to_number(..)` or `internal_function()` .

Comment: Thank you very much, I've found an implicit conversion inside the subselect in the view. c.DOC_TYPE in table0 is NUMBER, but lv.vetting_table in table2 is VARCHAR2. In this case to_char(c.DOC_TYPE) solved an issue. Thank you!!!